# round div with a img inside width<height height<width HTML / CSS

Tags: html, css, image, rounding

so i have a round div with a img inside. The problem is:

```
#mydiv
{
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
overflow: hidden;
border-radius: 25px;
}
```

Now, if a user uploads a picture with less height than width
i can take height: 50px and width: auto;

but if a user uploads a picture with less width than height
i need to make height: auto; and width: 50px;

If its wrong, the div isnt filled with this img.

How i can solve it?

sorry, im pupil in germany so i cant write well :/

Comment: you can set `#mydiv img {min-height:100%; min-width:100%;}` so it should fill the div when the img is too small to start with ;)

Answer (score 2):

Put the image in css :

*background: url(img/...) no-repeat center center;
background-size: cover;*

That's the way !

Comment: Dont forget, also need:
    Background-size:cover
..so that it fills the container rather than hitting the bounding box and stops scaling.

Comment: thanks, works! So easy if someone had just the idea. +1